# How to select and order columns in a dataframe using an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have a fairly lage dataframe, df2 (~50,000 rows x 2,000 columns). The column headings are sample names. Separately, I have a dataframe, df1, with a list of samples I want to include in my analysis as the df1 index. I want to use the list of samples from df1 index to select only the columns from df2 for those selected samples, discarding the rest. I also want to preserve the sample order from the df1 index.

Example data:

```
# df1
data1 = {'Sample': ['Sample_A','Sample_D', 'Sample_E'], 
        'Location': ['Bangladesh', 'Myanmar', 'Thailand'],
        'Year':[2012, 2014, 2015]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df1.set_index('Sample')

# df2
data2 = {'Num': ['Value_1','Value_2','Value_3','Value_4','Value_5'], 
        'Sample_A': [0,1,0,0,1],
        'Sample_B':[0,0,1,0,0],
        'Sample_C':[1,0,0,0,1],
        'Sample_D':[0,0,1,1,0]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df2.set_index('Num')
```

First I generate the list of samples I want from the index of df1, e.g.

```
samples = df1['Sample'].tolist()
```

'samples' is then,

```
['Sample_A', 'Sample_D', 'Sample_E']
```

And using 'samples', my desired output dataframe, df3, should look like:

```
index  Sample_A  Sample_D
Value_1  0  0
Value_2  1  0
Value_3  0  1
Value_4  0  1
Value_5  1  0
```

But if I use

```
df3 = df2[samples]
```

Then I get the error message:

```
"['Sample_E'] not in index"
```

So how do I ignore samples that are not found in df2 to avoid this error message?

UPDATE
The solution that worked -

```
# 1. Define samples to use from df1
samples = df1['Sample'].tolist()
# Only include samples that are found in df2 as well
final_samples = list(set(list(df2.columns)) & set(samples ))
# Make new df with columns corresponding to final_samples
df3 = df2.loc[:, final_samples]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this..

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", usecols=['Sample_A','Sample_D']).fillna('')
print(df)
```

Selecting all of the rows and some columns, It is possible to select all of the rows by using a single colon.

```
>>> df.loc[:, ['Sample_A','Sample_D']]
```

Your answer from the dataset you provided:

```
>>> data2 = {'Num': ['Value_1','Value_2','Value_3','Value_4','Value_5'],
...         'Sample_A': [0,1,0,0,1],
...         'Sample_B':[0,0,1,0,0],
...         'Sample_C':[1,0,0,0,1],
...         'Sample_D':[0,0,1,1,0]}
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
>>> df2.set_index('Num').loc[:, ['Sample_A','Sample_D']]
         Sample_A  Sample_D
Num
Value_1         0         0
Value_2         1         0
Value_3         0         1
Value_4         0         1
Value_5         1         0
```

=====================================

```
>>> df3 = df2.loc[:, samples]
>>> df3
   Sample_A  Sample_D  Sample_E
0         0         0       NaN
1         1         0       NaN
2         0         1       NaN
3         0         1       NaN
4         1         0       NaN
```

OR

```
>>> df3 = df2.reindex(columns=samples)
>>> df3
   Sample_A  Sample_D  Sample_E
0         0         0       NaN
1         1         0       NaN
2         0         1       NaN
3         0         1       NaN
4         1         0       NaN
```

Comment: @jezrael, thnx  :-) borrowed from you only .

Comment: 'df3 = df2.reindex(columns=samples)' also works perfectly and very succinct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way. They columns array is in Order which you actually want.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'index': ['Value_1','Value_2','Value_3','Value_4','Value_5'], 
        'Sample_A': [0,1,0,0,1],
        'Sample_B':[0,0,1,0,0],
        'Sample_C':[1,0,0,0,1],
        'Sample_D':[0,0,1,1,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index('index')
df1 = df[['index']+['Sample_A','Sample_D']]
```

output:

```
     index  Sample_A  Sample_D
0  Value_1         0         0
1  Value_2         1         0
2  Value_3         0         1
3  Value_4         0         1
4  Value_5         1         0
```

but to ignore the missing columns take the columns only belong `df` on which you're doing analysis.

```
samples = ['index', 'Sample_A', 'Sample_D','Extra_Sample']
final_samples = list(set(list(df1.columns)) & set(samples ))
```

Now you can pass the `final_samples` which is having only df2 columns.

```
df3 = df2[final_samples]
```

Comment: What format does the list of samples need to be in - I extract it from the index column of another dataframe. I've tried - 
  samples = df1['Samples'].astype(str)
And then using your code
  df3 = df2[[samples]]
But get an error message.

Comment: you just have to keep them in a list of strings or indexes (of current dataframe) (with the order).

Comment: `samples = df1['Samples'].tolist()` then pass it 
`df3 = df2[samples]`

Comment: @WillHamilton, can you publish your dataframe code you are processing to reproduce to get the correct answer.

Comment: @pygo I have added the code I use to generate the sample list

Comment: @CSMaverick I get an error message using your solution, "['Sample_Z'] not in index", where Sample_Z looks like it is in my list of samples I want to analyse but not in the main dataframe (df2 in my question). So I need a way of just ignoring any missing samples like that.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check and let me know that's what u needed. if not explain steps to reproduce the issues in your question.

Comment: @CSMaverick I have updated my question; it should have everything self-contained for solving now. The error message from your solution arises because of missing samples in my dataframes. I need a way of just ignoring missing samples so I don't get the error message.

Comment: @WillHamilton, see the updated answer if that works for you.

Comment: @pygo that works but it changes the order of the columns from my starting order -in my Q, df1 row order is Sample_A, Sample_D, Sample_E. But when I run 'final_samples = list(set(list(df2.columns)) & set(samples ))' and then 'df3 = df2[final_samples]', then df3 comes out with column order 'Sample_D, Sample_A' when it should be 'Sample_A, Sample_D'

Comment: @WillHamilton, try `df3 = df2.loc[:, samples]` it works for me

Comment: @WillHamilton, if it works for you then you can accept it as a answer.

Comment: @pygo how do I do that?

Comment: you can click on ✔ to accept the answer. which one is useful and worked.